# Вызов функции-члена из лямбда-функции

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть класс, в котором два метода. Один - `public`, второй - `private`. В `public`-методе создаю лямбду и хочу вызвать в ней `private` метод класса.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Достаточно передать `this` в область захвата лямбды:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    void g() { 
        std::cout << "public\n"; 
        auto l = [this]() { std::cout << "lambda\n"; f(); };
        l();
    }
private:
    void f() { std::cout << "private\n"; }
};

int main()
{
     S s;
     s.g();
}
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P2vhTNUnFrLVVJWX)</kbd>